# Лопать в значении "есть"

Tags: этимология

Есть просторечное слово "лопать" в значении "есть, кушать". Но я задумалась: а почему, собственно, "лопать"? Лопать можно, например, воздушный шарик. К чему тут еда?

Comment: Где-то читала, что есть слово «лопа», что значит «обжора».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть мнение, что это звукоподражание, связанное чередованием гласных с ла́пать, лепета́ть.То, что льётся и поглощается в больших количествах,делается грубо, с лопаньем.
Слово общеславянское.Первоначально ло́па - "обжора, болтун", укр. ло́пати, ст.-слав. лопотивъ "косноязычный", болг. ло́пам, ло́пна "жру, поглощаю", сербохорв. ло̀пити "литься в большом количестве, сильно болеть", словен. lópati, lóраm "хлопать, лопаться", чеш. lороt "хлопоты", lopotiti "работать до изнеможения, хлопотать".

Даль возводит ЛОПАТЬ к диалектам : лопоть (от лопотать, хлопать, болтаться )- арханг. вят. сиб." верхняя одежда",  простая, рабочая, плохая, ветхая. Лопотное ср. сиб.- одежда из оленьих шкур. лопошки - тверск. пеленки, ветошь.

Лопать или лопаться, лопнуть - ломаться от гнету, подламываться; рваться от натуги; разрываться от распору изнутри;Синонимы - трескаться. лопать, трескать, жрать, жущерить, уплетать; есть много, жадно, по-собачьи.

У олончан -  кричать, орать изо всех сил; вят.-  бить без пощады.

Так что ЛОПАТЬ - "грубо жрать,шумно глотая с лопаньем" - "жадно есть, издавая треск",(отсюда просторечие трескать, натрескался) - просторечие, тогда как ЕСТЬ - нейтральное, кушать - от "кусать", откушать - только попробовать кусочек, отведать.